# Product of the elements cannot be 1

Tags: finite-groups

I have to show in a group $G$ of order $4k+2$ the product of the elements cannot be $1$.

What I got so far is that there exists a subgroup $H$ of index $2$ in $G$ (considering left regular representation on $G$).Then $G/H$ is abelian. Now consider the corresponding product of the cosets of $H$, i.e, $x_1x_2\dots x_nH$ where $n=4k+2$, we can arrange this product in such a way that this product becomes $x_1x_2\dots x_mH$ (after some renaming) where $m$ is also odd where each $x_i$ is of order $2$. I cannot proceed further.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: "The product" is not well-defined unless you are talking abelian groups.

Comment: It need not to be well defined bt not to be 1

Comment: It holds for any order of the product, though. Once you have a subgroup of index 2, $G/H$ has order 2, and the only group of order 2 is $\{-1,1\}$, up to isomorphism. The image in $G/H$ of a product of all elements will be $(-1)^{2k+1}1^{2+k1}=-1$ which can't be the image of $1$ under a homomorphism.

Comment: Exactly U r right,my approach was wrong,i was taking it elementwise considring different order rather than cosets of H...thank U.

Comment: My objection is to the usage of the term "the" in "the product." It implies there is a single value. I'd prefer a formulation like, "No product all the elements of $G$ is $1$." It's really a small nit, not a big deal.

Comment: I understand it should no be 'the' before product,it depends on the order of the elements,U were right @ Thomas Andrews

Comment: How did you prove the existence of $H$ ?

Comment: Consider the multiplication map from G to G by a order 2 element in G,this will give u an on odd permutation